# can gspread create/manipulate a chart?

Tags: gspread

i have a python script using gspread that creates a new spreadsheet every month and performs updates on the current month sheet (ie sheet 2019-09).

when a new month is detected, i create a new sheet with the month as the name, and copy everything from the previous month, so as to start with a new fresh template.

the problem i have is there's a chart in the sheet that has specific date ranges that reference the current month sheep (ie '2019-09 Trend'!A4:B35).

so my question is, how can i edit this chart when a new month sheet is created?  or do i need to just create the chart somehow and specify the chart values?  i just dont see any reference to chart in gspread.

thanks
kirk